# Programmatically compiling babel into one file

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a file that I am compiling dynamically using babel. This is a react component that has `import`s, I would like to compile it to a single string containing es5 code. However, when doing so only the uppermost file is being compiled, all `import` statements are compiled into `require` statements, which is standard. Is there a way to disable this behavior and compile everything into one string. This must be done programmatically.

```
babel.transform(component, {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
}).code
```

component here is the raw es6 code read from the file.